# Unique number between 0 to 255 across the processes

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to generate a unique number between 0 to 255. This number must be unique across the processes. So If my application has multiple instances each instance will be given a unique number between 0 to 255. Of course, maximum number of instances my application can have are 256.

As suggested by [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123685/brad), Using a file is always as an option. But I am wondering if there are any **windows** API to do so?

Is this something I can do in C++?

Comment: If you're keeping track of the number of instances at a given time, the unique number assigned to a new instance could be that number.

Comment: Well, I want to put unique id generator in a dll which can be used by different applications. I should have said, that maximum number of processes consuming this dll are 256.

Comment: @JohnBupit: No, wouldn't work. Process 1 gets 0, process 2 gets 1, process 1 dies, process 3 gets 1 again.

Comment: @Neo, if your question is answered, please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows you can create [shared memory or a shared data segment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0(v=vs.90).aspx) in your DLL.  Since you are sharing a single integer from a single DLL it may be simpler to use a shared data segment.

```
#pragma data_seg (".myseg")
   int sharedCounter = 0; 
#pragma data_seg()
```

You will want to use an [interlocked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614(v=vs.85).aspx) function to access that since it is shared across processes:

```
int myAppId = InterlockedIncrement(&sharedCounter);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, you can use shared memory to exchange data between the processes.

Since you are only interested in unique IDs between 0-255, and I assuming it is OK for any given ID to be reused after a process is done using it (so 256 unique IDs between 256 *concurrent* processes, right?). If so, you could store a 256-element boolean array in the shared memory, and when a new process loads the DLL it can look for an available slot in the array, set it to true, and use the slot index as its unique ID.  When the DLL is unloaded, have it reset the array slot to false for a later process to use.  You can use a named mutex via `CreateMutex()` to synchronize access to the array across processes.

Something like this:

```
#pragma data_seg (".myseg")
bool AppsInUse[256] = {0};
#pragma data_seg()

HANDLE hMutex = NULL;
int UniqueID = -1;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch( fdwReason ) 
    { 
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hinstDLL);
            hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, TEXT("MyMutex"));
            if (hMutex == NULL)
                return FALSE;
            if (WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, 5000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
                {
                    if (!AppsInUse[i])
                    {
                        AppsInUse[i] = true;
                        UniqueID = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
            }
            if (UniqueID == -1)
                return FALSE;
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            if (UniqueID != -1)
            {
                if (WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, 1000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                    AppsInUse[UniqueID] = false;
                    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
                }
                UniqueID = -1;
            }
            if (hMutex != NULL)
            {
                CloseHandle(hMutex);
                hMutex = NULL;
            }
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

If your compiler does not support `#pragma data_seg`, you can use `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` to allocate a shared array dynamically instead:

```
HANDLE hMapping = NULL;
bool* AppsInUse = NULL;
HANDLE hMutex = NULL;
int UniqueID = -1;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch( fdwReason ) 
    { 
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hinstDLL);
            hMapping = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(bool) * 256, TEXT("MyArray"));
            if (hMapping == NULL)
                return FALSE;
            bool bDoInit = (GetLastError() != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS);
            AppsInUse = (bool*) MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, sizeof(bool) * 256);
            if (AppsInUse == NULL)
                return FALSE;
            if (bDoInit) ZeroMemory(AppsInUse, sizeof(bool) * 256);
            hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, TEXT("MyMutex"));
            if (hMutex == NULL)
                return FALSE;
            if (WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, 5000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
                {
                    if (!AppsInUse[i])
                    {
                        AppsInUse[i] = true;
                        UniqueID = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
            }
            if (UniqueID == -1)
                return FALSE;
            break;
        }

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            if (UniqueID != -1)
            {
                if (WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, 1000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                    AppsInUse[UniqueID] = false;
                    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
                }
                UniqueID = -1;
            }
            if (AppsInUse != NULL)
            {
                UnmapViewOfFile(AppsInUse);
                AppsInUse = NULL;
            }
            if (hMapping != NULL)
            {
                CloseHandle(hMapping);
                hMapping = NULL;
            }
            if (hMutex != NULL)
            {
                CloseHandle(hMutex);
                hMutex = NULL;
            }
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically by a C++ construct.  You could however keep the current number in a file, and when a process starts up, you could read the file and increment the number.  You would need locking on the file so two processes don't update it at the same time.  You would also need a way to detect a process it the only one of it's kind and start over.

How to achieve both of those last requirements are likely to turn out to be specific to your language and operating system.

Comment: Yes, using a file is always as an option. I was wondering if there are any windows API to do so?

Comment: Very OS specific, but yes - on Windows you can create shared memory.  For example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx